# Cálculos com String em Java

Tags: java, android, matemática, tipagem

Preciso retirar a média de alguns números que recebo via JSON no formato de `String`s, esse calculo deve retornar um valor para que eu possa setá-lo dentro de um `TextView` no Android, porém não estou conseguindo formatar essa resposta para que venha apenas com uma casa decimal (exemplo: o cálculo retorne 46.7) ele está retornando um valor muito maior:

```
private Float calculateAverage(Powerstats powerstats) {
    float sum;

    sum = Float.parseFloat("70" + "26" + "83"
                + "55" + "81" + "69");
    
    return sum / 6;
}
```

o retorno dessa função deveria ser um número formatado com apenas 1 casa decimal.

Comment: Essa soma de strings ai nao está fazendo o que voce acha q está.  Voce sabe que sinal de + nao soma strings, e sim **CONCATENA**? É isso que ocorre: https://ideone.com/wr1I4D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Na forma como você colocou não faz sentido fazer isso, se você já tem os números use-os de forma direta, na verdade nem precisa fazer contas. Mas considerando que na verdade sejam variáveis você tem que aplicar o `parseFloat()` em cada uma das variáveis, e com o número individual convertido fazer a soma. Tem ainda uma série de coisas erradas que podem acontecer aí (por exemplo a pessoa digitar algo que não é um número), mas isso é outro assunto. Seria algo assim para duas variáveis:

```
return (Float.parseFloat(a) + Float.parseFloat(b)) / 2;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2M1JcR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ezgwmctq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/SumStringsAsNumbers.java).

Comment: Era isso mesmo, coloquei os valores ali fixos apenas para exemplificar, cada valor vem de uma classe modelo, no caso eu estava fazendo Float.parseFloat(a + b) e por isso acabava concatenando as Strings e não somando-as